# Can "OPAQUE-over-TLS" authentication be optimized?

Tags: authentication, tls, passwords, pake

So while discussing the issues of password-hashing off-loading [in our chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48007998#48007998) I noticed that it's easy to extend [OPAQUE](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/163) ([CFRG draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-krawczyk-cfrg-opaque)) to essentially be a better standard password based authentication when executed over TLS. Namely one could simply append a message $F_K(2)$ (for some pre-defined PRF $F$) from the client to the server and only if the client arrived at the correct shared secret $K$ the server will get the same PRF evaluation value and confirm the authentication.

Now my question is:
**This protocol contains the full OPAQUE key-exchange, can it be optimized to remove heavy computations (such as exponentations) from either side without compromising security while keeping the number of sent messages or even lowering it?**

To give a more concrete direction: Can we remove parts of the (or even the complete) key exchange and only rely on the OPRF (or a parallel instance)?

---

For your convenience, here is the overview of the protocol:

\begin{align}
U\to S:&\ \text{username}, H'(\text{pw})^r, g^x\\
S\to U:&\ g^y, H'(\text{pw})^{rk}, c\\
U\to S:&\ F_K(2)\\
\end{align}

with $r$ being chosen uniformly at random for each protocol run by the user $U$, same with $x$, $y$ is chosen the same way by the server, $k$ is a static per-user server-side secret, $\text{Rwd}=H(\text{pw},H'(\text{pw})^k)$ and $c=\operatorname{Enc}_{\text{Rwd}}(p_u,P_u,P_s)$ where $P_x$ is $x$'s public key and $p_x$ is $x's$ private DH key. The server also retrieves $p_s$ based on the username (as well as $P_u,P_s$) and $K$ is the result of securely combining ([HMQV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MQV#MQV_vs_HMQV)) $(x,p_u,P_s,g^y)$ or $(y,p_s,P_u,g^x)$.

Comment: I'm now mildly sure that the entire key-exchange can be dropped as recovery of the OPRF output is equivalent to successfully being the client as then one can easily recover the private DH keys